# Recurrence relation to explicit formula

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

The recurrence is
$$a_{n+7}=5 \cdot 6^{n} + 6 \cdot a_{n+6} - 5 \cdot a_{n}$$
where $a_{6}=1$ and $a_i=0$ for $i<6$ .

I can't find a method that works because of the $6^{n}$ term.

Example of first step:
$$ a_7=5 \cdot 6^0 + 6 \cdot a_6 - 5 \cdot a_0 = 5 + 6 = 11 $$
First few steps:
$$a_7=11, a_8=96, a_9=756, a_{10}=5616, a_{11}=40176, a_{12}=279936, $$$$a_{13}=1912891, a_{14}=12876971, a_{15}=85659426, a_{16}=564341256$$

Note that $a_n$ is the number of ways to throw a die n times where at least once you got '6' 6 times in a row, so $a_n / 6^n$ is the probabilty of this happening in n throws.

Comment: The final formula is extremely simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make $a_n=6^n \,b_n$ to obtain the simple
$$5 b_n-279936 b_{n+6}+279936 b_{n+7}-5=0$$
Now, make $b_n=c_n+1$ to get rid of the constant term
$$5 c_n-279936 c_{n+6}+279936 c_{n+7}=0$$

Comment: I realized that writing out a_(n+8) then solving for 6^n for both equations also works. Your method with substitutions is much more elegant and simple though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this recurrence using a standard linear algebra trick.

Here is the sage code to showcase the idea:

```
M = Matrix(
    QQ, [
        [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5, 5],
        [1, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0 ,0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
    ]
)
v = vector([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
for i in range(20):
    print(i, (M ** i * v)[6])
```

which gives you

```
(0, 0)
(1, 0)
(2, 0)
(3, 0)
(4, 0)
(5, 0)
(6, 1)
(7, 11)
(8, 96)
(9, 756)
(10, 5616)
(11, 40176)
(12, 279936)
(13, 1912891)
(14, 12876971)
(15, 85659426)
(16, 564341256)
(17, 3688350336)
(18, 23943886416)
(19, 154545830496)
```

and also:

```
M.minimal_polynomial()
>>> x^8 - 12*x^7 + 36*x^6 + 5*x - 30
```

So if you want to compute $a_n$ you can compute $q = x ^ n \mod p$ (with p that minimal polynomial) and then $a_n = (q(M) \times v)_7$.

This is an effective way of computing $a_n$. If you want a closed formula you can get one by using the roots of $p$ (which are complex btw).

Comment: I don't understand the sage code but I recognize that minimal polynomial so I'm guessing we are on the same track. Many thanks